# Convert dictionary value into list does not work in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

This works without in a function.

```
v = list(dic.values()) #  V is a list.
```

But if I put it in a function, for example:

```
def test(list):
    result={}
    for i in l:
        result[i]=result.get(i,0)+1
    v = result.values()
    return list(v)
l=[1,2,1,1,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,3,7]
print(test(l))
```

it raise error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `repNone.py`, line 83, in <module>
    print(test(l))
  File "`repNone.py`", line 81, in test
    return list(v)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: In the function you shadowed it by naming the (unused, you're accessing `l` as a global) parameter `list`.

Comment: More specifically, your function parameter named "list" overwrites the definition of the actual type `list`.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always don't use [Built-in Function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) *(like `list`)* as variables, You use `list` as variable**

In your function you pass `l` as variable with name `list` then when you use `list(v)` you got an error because you can not call variable.

you did this:

```
>>> def test(list):
        ...
...     return list(v) # <- got error because here list is variable and you call this.
```

change your code like this:

```
>>> def test(lst):
        ...
...     return list(v)
```

Comment: Great catch! thanks. @user1740577